# node-redis/search query elements by geospatial position and additional indexes

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I want to be able to query elements in a redis cache based on 3 different indexes. Those indexes would be:

1. A MAC address stored as a `String`.
2. A `number`.
3. A `latitude` and `longitude`(to be able to query spatially).

I have seen that Redis has support for multi indexing using redis search and native geospatial api.

so using nodejs and node-redis I have written the following index:

```js
client.ft.create(
            'idx:cits',
            {
                mid: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.TEXT
                },
                timestamp: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.NUMERIC,
                    sortable: true
                },
                position: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.GEO
                }
            },
            {
                ON: 'HASH',
                PREFIX: 'CITS'
            }
        )
```

Now, i would like to insert records on the database that include those 3 parameters plus an additional `String` that stores some payload. I have tried using

```js
await client.hSet('CITS:19123123:0:0:00:00:5e:00:53:af', {
        timestamp: 19123123,
        position: {latitude:0, longitude:0},
        mid: '00:00:5e:00:53:af',
        message: 'payload'
    })
```

But I get the following error:

```js
throw new TypeError('Invalid argument type');
                  ^

TypeError: Invalid argument type
```

So, i can't add the latitude and longitude that way, I also tried
using the module `ngeohash` and computing an [11 character wide geohash](https://redis.io/commands/geohash/#geohash-string-properties) like so:

```js
await client.hSet('CITS:19123123:0:0:00:00:5e:00:53:af', {
        timestamp: 19123123,
        position: geohash.encode(0, 0, 11),
        mid: '00:00:5e:00:53:af',
        message: 'payload'
    })
```

And it does not give any error but when using [redis search querys](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/query_syntax/#geo-filters-in-query) It does not find points near it.

Is it even possible what I am trying to do? If so, how would you input the data to the redis database?

Here is a minimal reproducible example (Im using `"ngeohash": "^0.6.3"` and `"redis": "^4.5.0"`):

```js
const { createClient, SchemaFieldTypes } = require('redis')
const geohash = require('ngeohash')

const client = createClient()

async function start(client) {
    await client.connect()
    try {
        // We only want to sort by these 3 values
        await client.ft.create(
            'idx:cits',
            {
                mid: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.TEXT
                },
                timestamp: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.NUMERIC,
                    sortable: true
                },
                position: {
                    type: SchemaFieldTypes.GEO
                }
            },
            {
                ON: 'HASH',
                PREFIX: 'CITS'
            }
        )
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message === 'Index already exists') {
            console.log('Skipping index creation as it already exists.')
        } else {
            console.error(e)
            process.exit(1)
        }
    }

    await client.hSet('CITS:19123123:0:0:00:00:5e:00:53:af', {
        timestamp: 19123123,
        position: geohash.encode(0, 0, 11),
        mid: '00:00:5e:00:53:af',
        message: 'payload'
    })
    await client.hSet('CITS:19123123:0.001:0.001:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', {
        timestamp: 19123123,
        position: geohash.encode(0.001, 0.001, 11),
        mid: 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff',
        message: 'payload'
    })

    const results = await client.ft.search(
        'idx:cits',
        '@position:[0 0 10000 km]'
    )
    console.log(results)

    await client.quit()
}

start(client)
```

Additionally, I would like to ask if there is maybe another type of database that better suits my needs. I have chosen redis because it offers low latency, and that is the biggest constraint in my environment(I will probably do more writes than reads per second). I only want it to act as a inmediate cache, as persistent data will be stored in another database that does not need to be fast.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `Invalid argument type` error because Redis does not support nested fields in hashes.

"GEO allows geographic range queries against the value in this attribute. The value of the attribute must be a string containing a longitude (first) and latitude separated by a comma" (https://redis.io/commands/ft.create/)

Comment: Thanks! that was exactly the problem, I did not see that in the docs!